# tap water and distilled water for electrolysis

Tags: acid-base, water, electrolysis

my water electrolyzer which I've built using [this](http://www.free-energy-info.com/Smack.pdf) pdf, produces less gas than I expected. In that file the author insists on using distilled water instead of tap water and I have used tap water. would it be the reason?

Why is it so important to use distilled water since it has high resistance for electricity?

Answer (score 3):

This article tells you to use distilled water because the salt in tap water will damage the booster. The author also tell you to add NaOH or KOH to the distilled water. Did you add these salts?

Comment: Yes I did add NaOH. So distilled water is only for the protection of booster and has nothing to do with performance?

Comment: In this article, the author only mentions the damage to the booster. Theoretically, tap water contains metal ions which are more prone to get electrons than hydrogen ions are, like Fe3+ and Cu2+, so they will hinder the process of producing hydrogen gas from water, while Na+ and K+ will not. It seems that the author considers tap water's damage to the booster more important than its ability to decrease the speed of making hydrogen gas, which should be the actual situation.